# Removing common prefix and suffix from set of messages

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, message-queue

I have a set of json messages coming from a message queue. I need to gather a related set of messages out of that (based on "location" field) and remove a common prefix and suffix from "description" field from all items in the set. Then dump that into elasticsearch.
For example if a set of description fields with same location field "London" look like this:

```
AAA BB I live in London CC DDD
AAA BB I want to eat fish & chips CC DDD
AAA BB My best friend is Alejandro CC DDD
```

I want to transform that into:

```
I live in London
I want to eat fish & chips
My best friend is Alejandro
```

Is there a way to do that in logstash or some other tool? I really don't want to write a special program just to pull messages from a source, aggregate and transform them and dump them into elasticsearch.
It's important to note that I need to remove prefix+suffix from messages with a common "location" field, and not across all messages.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use mutate gsub in your logstash configuration:

```
filter {
    mutate {
            gsub => ["fieldname","AAA BB ",""]
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html

Comment: Is there a way to do this without knowing the common prefix/suffix in advance? It can be different each time and I cannot hardcode it.

Comment: You can use regex inside (of course you need to know the format)